# Как динамически ставить и удалять таб панель(или как связать боковое меню с табами)

Tags: android, tab, android-navigation-drawer

Хочу сделать так. Открываю программу появляется главный активити. У него весь layout это контейнер который устанавливает в себя фрагменты. Также есть боковое меню navigation drower. И табы. Выглядит все так: 
Приложение открылость, установился первый фрагмент который соотвествует первому элементу бокового меню и первому табу. Дальше я с боковог меню выбираю второй фрагмент, и он устанавливается, а также выделяется второй таб. Если же я листаю свайпом в бок, то фрагменты так же меняются, и вместе с ними выделяются элемент меню и таб. И все это я могу сделать. Но в боковом меню есть еще некоторые элементы. Например личный кабинет, о нас, инфо и тд. И для них нет табов. И я хочу нажать например на элемент меню, для которого нет таба и отобоазить соотвествующий ему фрагмент на весь экран. Тоесть убрать табы и показать контент. А потом снова если открою боковое меню и выбиру элемент для которого есть табы, откроеся фрагмент и выделится таб. Я не заню делают ли так или нет. Новое активити для этого создавать не хочу. Подскате может это чтото типо антипаттерна или как это сделать. Вот примерно что я хочу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой главный активите это просто верикальный лейаут с айди  container  и тулбаром

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:elevation="4dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Табы я пытался вставить так

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".DashboardActivity">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:elevation="4dp" />
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Но они не отображаются без вью пейджера.

Comment: Покажите вашу разметку. Табы можно несколькими способами сделать. Как и меню левое. Без разметки что-то сказать сложно.

Comment: дровер это библиотека compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.3.4@aar') 
табы - android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
сейчас дополню вопрос

Comment: табы делал по примеру https://github.com/devcolibri/RemindMeProject

Comment: Ну... Попробуйте при вызове фрагмента нужного табам высоту в 0 или `wrap_content' назначать...